# save file created in isolated storage to phone memory

Tags: windows-phone-7

My application is generating a log file on isolated storage and i want to save that file in phone memory like we can do on other platforms like android.can anyone tell me how to do that.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "Phone Memory"?  Isolated storage is the on-device file storage location.  If you want the file contents in memory, read it into an appropriate structure.

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402541%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) may help you understand isolated storage better.

Comment: Can u tell me the best way to display the contents of that file which is in isolated storage..?

Comment: I want that file to be read somehow,may be saving it somewhere else where all applications can access it or reading it directly.

Comment: You can't share data between apps like this. In fact, if you want to share between apps you would probably have to implement a web service somewhere to do that.